# Use php/MySQL result in new query

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched around and haven't found anything similar, but it sounds like it should be pretty easy...

I have a search query that searches for a specific userID and displays that information for that user. However, I have one field (let's call it "favorite color" for this example) that will need to be manually updated frequently. So, I want to Search by userID, display the results, somehow re-use the original userID, and update the "favorite color" by the user entry. The part I can't figure out yet is how to store/re-use the userID.

The only way I can get it to work is -> 
Search for userID, display results and also populate two new text form fields with original userID as well as "favorite color" to be submitted again by a new UPDATE query. But I don't want the userID to be a text form field, I just want to store the variable use it again.
Does that make sense? =)

Here is a sample of my current code. BTW, it works 100% this way right now, just need to figure out how to store the variable instead of using it again in a text box where I submit the UPDATE query.

```
<div class="searchBox">
    <form method="POST" name="search" action="filter-update.php" class="form-wrapper cf">
        <input type="text" name="querySearch" placeholder="User ID" required>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="results">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['querySearch'])){
            $query = $_POST['querySearch'];
            $min_length = 8;

            if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){

                $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
                $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE userID = $query";
                $raw_results = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql) or die ('error getting data from database');
                if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){
                while ($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
                    echo "<div class='title'>User ID:</div><div class='info'>".$results['userID']."</div>";
                    echo "<div class='title'>Name:</div><div class='info'>".$results['name']."</div>";
                    echo "<div class='title'>Fav Color:</div><div class='info'>".$results['favColor']."</div>";
                    $userID = $results['userID'];

                    }
                }
                else { // if there is no matching rows do following
                    echo "No results";
                }

            }
            else{ // if query length is less than minimum
                echo "<br>Minimum length is ".$min_length;
            }
        }

    ?>
</div>
<div class="searchBox">
    <form method="POST" name="filterUpdate" action="filter-update.php" class="form-wrapper cf">
        <input type="text" name="UserID" value="<?php echo $userID;?>" required><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="favColor" placeholder="New favColor here..." required>
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="results">
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['filterUpdate'])){
            $queryFilter = $_POST['filterUpdate'];
            $userID = $_POST['userID'];
            $min_length = 1;

            if(strlen($queryFilter) >= $min_length){

                $queryFilter = htmlspecialchars($queryFilter);
                $userID = htmlspecialchars($userID);
                $queryFilter = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $queryFilter);
                $userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $userID);

                $sql = "UPDATE sites SET favColor = '$queryFilter' WHERE userID = '$userID'";
                $raw_results = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql) or die ('error getting data from database');

            }
            else{ // if query length is less than minimum
                echo "<br>Minimum length is ".$min_length;
            }
        }

    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, on one of the lines I tried to store the result in a variable ($userID = $results['userID'];), and it looks like it stores it if I echo it, but when I try to use it in my UPDATE statement it doesn't pass it through and is null.

Comment: You can hide the text field instead

Comment: Edit your question, don't comment with additional info.

Comment: input type = 'hidden"

Comment: @pvg thanks, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either of this:

**Hidden Field:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" value="<?php echo $userID;?>">
```

**Session:**

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
```

Don't know if this will work, but you can put the `$userID` above all the codes(like a global var).

Comment: Hidden input type works for me. I was so focused on trying to pass this variable through I didn't even think of the easiest method =) Thanks!